# graphics-amd-firmware - Unable to locate package - Bullseye

Tags: debian, amd-graphics

I just installed a new Radeon RX 6600 graphics card and I'm noticing that there is some choppiness playing video. My previous card was a R9 290X so I expected this one to be considerably faster.

Anyway, I'm trying to install graphics-amd-firmware but I'm getting an 'Unable to locate package' error. Is anyone else having trouble with this package? My sources.list contains the following:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-proposed-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free

deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This doesn't effect bullseye, but in future debian stable releases, non-free firmware won't be in `non-free`, it will be in its own "suite" called `non-free-firmware`.  This is already true for `sid` (unstable) and `testing`.   BTW, unless you actually need to download and rebuild debian source packages, you should probably comment out the `deb-src` lines - you can always un-comment them if/when you need them.

Answer (score 2):

The package you’re looking for is [`firmware-amd-graphics`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-amd-graphics), not `graphics-amd-firmware`.

Comment: Right, but why does the package manager seem to be blind? I can download it manually but it refuses to work using apt-get install.

Comment: Your question says you’re trying to install `graphics-amd-firmware`; that’s not the right name.

Comment: Apologize for the confusion. I was referring more to the fact that there seems to be something going on with these amd drivers and the Bullseye repository. I did manually install graphics-amd-firmware but I can't find libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 in the repository at all. So, as things stand right now, amdgpu is not being loaded and, unfortunately, AMD does not have a Debian-specific driver for download.

Comment: You’re looking for packages that don’t exist. It’s `firmware-amd-graphics` and `libdrm-amdgpu1`, not `graphics-amd-firmware` and `libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1`.

Comment: As of Debian Bookworm, hou might need to add the `non-free-firmware` component